# default Navbar not displaying properly

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my default navbar display like it's shown on bootstrap here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar

but it comes out displaying like this:https://gyazo.com/c4ad522abe61357054a5c3f5664e3c1f

I simply copy and pasted the code on bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Did you load the relevant CDN/packages in your project before copying the code?